# How to check if FileUpload control is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using LINQ to retrieve data from the Database, the variable name relative to link is "service".

the upDocument is the Id of a FileUpload control.

The objective is to delete the old file, before uploading a new one.
This is the code i came up with:

```
if ((service.image_url != null || service.image_url != "") &&
    (upDocument.FileName.Length != 0 || upDocument.PostedFile.ToString() != ""))
{
     if (File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(service.image_url)))
     {
          File.Delete(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(service.image_url));
     }
}
```

The problem that I have, is that although nothing is being loaded to the FileUpload the file is still being deleted. I made a breakpoint and checked it out... and contrary to what I was expecting the FileName.Length is not 0, and the postedFile.ToString() is not "".

How can I make a correct validation?

Comment: Your first condition (`service.image_url`) should use an and (`&&`), not an or (`||`).  However, it should actually call `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: By the way, `upDocument.PostedFile.ToString()` will always be `"HttpPostedFile"` because the `HttpPostedFile` class doesn't override `ToString`.  Therefore, there's no point in checking it.  You should check `HasFile` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the [`HasFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.hasfile.aspx) property, like this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(service.image_url) && upDocument.HasFile) { 
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(service.image_url)))
        File.Delete(Server.MapPath(service.image_url));
}
```

By the way, inside an ASP.Net page, you don't need to write `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`, so you can simply write `Server.MapPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're deleting the file if `service.image_url` is `null` **OR** if it's `""`.  That condition will always be true, since it can't be both `null` and `""` at the same time.

You should write `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(service.image_url)`, as I wrote in my first answer.